# Post edits bug: Not saving changes

Tags: bug, edits

I happened to me too many times. I edit a post, usually questions, I add the description of the changes, and then I press to Save to suggest the edit, but it acts the same as I pressed to cancel. Nothing happens and the web shows the post again, without the:

> "Thanks for your edit, wait until is peer reviewed"

Losing all the changes and forcing me to do all the work again.
Is this something that is happening to somebody else? Maybe because of using Chrome?

Comment: @J.Steen I know, but sometimes changes are not applied and nothing happens, and I have to do all the work again to suggest the edit again.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Please include the little tidbit that you already know about suggested edits in your question. =)

Comment: What version of Chrome and you do have JavaScript enabled, do you?

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby Lastest version I think (24.0.1312.52 m). And yes, javascript enabled. It only happens sometimes, not always.

Comment: Do you have a (rough) time of an example of this happening, and a link to the particular post that you were editing? This would help tracking down the issue.

Comment: @balpha No sorry, but I will track here the next time that happens. Time and post. Thanks.

Comment: @balpha Happened right now in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14600416/file-download-dialog-is-not-working-when-execute-on-a-modal-pop-up-page-any-wor

Comment: Okay thanks; looking.

Comment: Definitely something wonky there. I see you resubmitted the suggestion, and it worked fine the second time.